# Redis backed cron style scheduler for reliability in clustered environments

Tags: java, redis

I came up empty handed in search of an alternative to Quartz for scheduling Crons in a clustered/distributed environment. Redisson has a scheduler, but it came with its own issues:

- https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4020
- https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3991
- https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4321

I wanted to improve upon what’s already available by:

1. Using Redis instead of a database for obtaining locks
2. Protecting against machines potentially not having their clocks perfectly synchronized
3. Protecting against mismatched app versions running conflicting Crons
4. Protecting against the Redis cache suddenly being flushed
5. Allowing for use with Redis clusters
6. Allowing cron-unique specifications for tolerance of late tasks (e.g Should this cron still run if it’s half an hour late because all instances of the app were offline?)

I ended up putting this together using Reddison to obtain Redis locks:

```
public class CronScheduler {

private static final int POLL_EVERY = 1000; // milliseconds
private static final Set<Cron> KNOWN_CRONS = new HashSet<>();
private static final ObjectMapper JSON_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

static {
    try {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        for (ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(Cron.class.getPackageName())) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(info.getName());
            if (!Cron.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) || Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers())) continue;
            KNOWN_CRONS.add((Cron) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


private final ScheduledExecutorService poller = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private final ExecutorService workers = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

private CronScheduler(App app, RedissonClient client) {
    final RMap<String, String> schedules = client.getMap("cronScheduler:schedules");
    poller.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        KNOWN_CRONS.parallelStream().forEach(cron -> {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                if (!schedules.containsKey(cron.getName())) insertCronData(cron, schedules, client); // Register cron
                JsonNode node = readTree(JSON_MAPPER, schedules.get(cron.getName()));
                if (node.get("disabled").booleanValue()) return; // This cron is disabled, don't process
                if (node.get("version").intValue() > cron.getVersion()) return; // Cron version is newer than this app, don't process
                RBucket<Long> next = client.getBucket("cronScheduler:" + cron + ":next");
                Long leftToWait = next.get() - Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
                if (leftToWait > 0) return; // Not time yet, don't process
                Lock lock = client.getLock("cronScheduler:" + cron + ":lock");
                if (!lock.tryLock()) return; // Someone else got it first, don't process
                if (cron.getLateTolerance() <= 0 || cron.getLateTolerance() * 1000 + leftToWait > 0) {
                    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> cron.accept(app)); // We got to it in time, so process
                }
                next.set(cron.getSchedule().nextTimeAfter(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
                lock.unlock();
            }, workers).orTimeout(POLL_EVERY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        });
    }, 0, POLL_EVERY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private static final void insertCronData(Cron cron, RMap<String, String> schedules, RedissonClient client) {
    String schedule = schedules.get(cron.getName());
    ObjectNode node = schedule != null ? readTree(JSON_MAPPER, schedule) : JSON_MAPPER.createObjectNode();
    if (node.get("version") == null || node.get("version").intValue() < cron.getVersion()) {
        Lock lock = client.getLock("cronScheduler:" + cron + ":lock");
        lock.lock(); // Don't want the Cron to go off until all of our data is updated
        ZonedDateTime date = cron.getSchedule().nextTimeAfter(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        client.getBucket("cronScheduler:" + cron + ":next").set(date.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        node.put("disabled", cron.isDisabled());
        node.put("version", cron.getVersion());
        schedules.put(cron.getName(), node.toString());
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public static CronScheduler initialize(App app) {
    return new CronScheduler(app, app.storage().getRedis().getClient());
}

private static final ObjectNode readTree(ObjectMapper mapper, String key) {
    try {
        return (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(key);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void shutdown() {
    try {
        poller.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        workers.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/justisr/b5e68ab94dfb00afe3a2aa5be2378889

The static block just loads all classes in the same package as my "Cron" abstract class and registers them if they’re a Cron. (So I don’t have to manually register each one explicitly).

Whenever a Cron is run, it gets provided the App instance and it can do whatever the implementation needs to with it.

I’ve run tests (spawning 50 different app instances on 2 different JVMs simultaneously) and everything works as expected. No overlap. However, I’m working alone on this and it’s easy to get tunnel vision when you can only ever address the issues that you’re aware of.

Have I overlooked anything that could cause issues? As always, nitpick anything please.